# Storing the list items into a variable after filtering by using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I got a list of items, want to filter the list based on column distinct value(i.e based on Level) and also after filtering need to get the count and store them as an int variable.
Can anyone please help me.

```
**List**

   Public Class Totalitems
    {
     public string ItemName;
     public string ItemId;
     public string ItemGroup;
     public int Level;
    } 

    Id= "123asd";

    List<Totalitems> l_items = this.getslist(Id);

       /*How to filter based on distinct level */

      /*  var filteredItems = (
            from p in l_items 
           select p.Level)
            .Distinct();  */                       

    **Finally:**
        //Stores the elements contained in the List into a variable
        int totalItemsafterFiltering = l_FilteredItems.Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `GroupBy` for this task:

```
var numberOfDifferentLevels = l_items.GroupBy(x => x.Level).Count();
```

`GroupBy` is especially useful, if you want to do something with the actual elements in the group. For example, you might want to know how many items per level there are:

```
var itemsPerLevel = l_items.GroupBy(x => x.Level)
                           .Select(x => new { Level = x.Key,
                                              NumberOfItems = x.Count() });
```

Another approach when you really only care about the number of distinct levels, is the following:

```
var numberOfDifferentLevels = l_items.Select(x => x.Level).Distinct().Count();
```